# Java lambdas (JSR 335): Why "eliminate support for unbound inner class constructor references"?

Tags: java, jsr335

In the [current JSR 335 draft](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Edlsmith/jsr335-0.6.3/), it's mentioned in the change log [entry for 0.6.0](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Edlsmith/jsr335-0.6.3/#0.6.0) that it "eliminated support for unbound inner class constructor references".

To illustrate, suppose you have an outer class named `A` and an inner class named `B`, and you want a function that takes an `A` and creates a new `B` instance:

```java
Function<A, A.B> foo = a -> a.new B();
```

Prior to 0.6.0, you can also use the constructor reference syntax to do the same thing (it's even documented in [State of the Lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html)):

```java
Function<A, A.B> foo = A.B::new;
```

As mentioned above, that syntax is no longer supported in 0.6.0. I'm really curious to know why.

I've looked through the archives for the [`lambda-spec-experts`](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-spec-experts/) and [`lambda-dev`](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/) mailing lists, and cannot find any information about it.

Comment: Do you really want to do that? Do you think it is obvious to even experienced Java programmers what is going on from that line alone?

Comment: On the JVM level, inner class constructors are just constructors that additionally take a reference to the outer class. So the mental model is not surprising to me, at least. Granted, I'm not particularly trying to defend its use in a constructor reference expression, just trying to understand the rationale for its removal.

Answer (score 0):

It's evident that the 'new' is a keyword, not a method, and that all involvment of 'new' as a method are special cases in the compiler. I can easily imagine they wanted to clean up the compiler of least likely usages which have trivial workarounds.

Speculation: there maybe also some collisions/ambiguities to resolve with upcoming JLS we don't know about yet, and this is a transition change to minimize regressions. 5-6 years after your question, do you suffer at all from this change? LOL