# Java 8 lambda predicate chaining?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I can't get it to compile, is it even possible to chain predicate lambdas?

```
Arrays.asList("1","2","3").stream().filter( (e -> e=="1" ).or(e-> e=="2") ).count();
```

Or only way is to explicitly create a predicate and then combine like so:

```
Predicate<String> isOne= e -> e=="1";
Arrays.asList("1","2","3").stream().filter( isOne.or(e -> e=="2") ).count();
```

Or is there more "functionally elegant" way to achieve same thing?

Comment: Can you give a better example? Because in the given example, `e -> e == "1" || e == "2"` would be a simpler solution than joining two predicates.

Comment: I think the `or` method is for case when you already have one predicate, and you vant to chain it with other. If you are writing both predicates, you can combine them into one direcctly, no need for `or` method.

Comment: Also, as I highlighted in my answer, use `equals()` to compare strings, don't use `==` (unless you are sure that all the strings being compared are interned---which is _not_ the case the vast majority of the time).

Comment: @nosid, Actually, i don't think i can provide an example that couldn't be resolved using || or && since Predicate has to return boolean. I just locked myself on finding a functional solution.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young yes i know to use `equals()` and i specifically didn't use it in this code so the part of code i had questions about was clearly visible.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You *can* use:

```
((Predicate<String>) e -> e.equals("1")).or(e -> e.equals("2"))
```

but it's not very elegant. If you're specifying the conditions in-line, just use one lambda:

```
e -> e.equals("1") || e.equals("2")
```

Comment: Lambda expressions have no intrinsic type; they are converted to their target type, which must be a functional interface.  The problem here is that it doesn't know what target type to use the for first lambda expression.  This cacades; it can't know what `or()` method to invoke.  The example in this answer shows providing a target type for the first lambda with a cast, which is one of your options for re-injecting the type information you need.

Comment: @BrianGoetz +1 Totally that, and nice to see a comment from the spec lead of JSR 335 himself. :-D On which note, maybe you'd know the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17203781/13)? :-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Thanks! second part is obviously the cleanest solution, i just locked myself on finding a solution with combining lambdas and missed the obvious. 
And first part of your answer is exactly what i was trying to do.

Comment: @BrianGoetz thats exactly the missing piece of theory i needed :)... And to think i stopped crunching through "Java Concurrency in Practice" to play with lambdas and streams :)

Answer (score 10):

I was working on a similar problem of predicate chaining and came up with the following

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> chain (Function<T,Predicate<T>> mapFn, T[]args) {
    return Arrays.asList(args)
        .stream()
        .map(x->mapFn.apply(x))
        .reduce(p->false, Predicate::or);
}
```

The first parameter to chain is a lambda (Function) that returns a lambda (Predicate) so it needs a couple of arrows

```
public static void yourExample() {
    String[] filterVals = { "1", "2" };

    Arrays.asList("1","2","3")
        .stream()
        .filter(chain(x-> (y-> y.equals(x)), filterVals))
        .count();
}
```

For comparison, here is what I was trying to achieve...

```
public static void myExample() {
    String[] suffixes = { ".png", ".bmp" };
    Predicate<String> p = chain (x-> y-> y.endsWith(x), suffixes);
    File[] graphics = new File("D:/TEMP").listFiles((dir,name)->p.test(name));
    Arrays.asList(graphics).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, I adapted your method as a BiFunction like this BiFunction<List<String>,Function<String,Predicate<String>>, Predicate<String>> chainFilter = 
  (args,f)->args.stream().map(s->f.apply(s))
  .reduce(pr->false, Predicate::or);

Answer (score 9):

You can use with magic method $:

```java
<T> Predicate<T> $(Predicate<T> p) {
     return p;
}

Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3").stream().filter( $(e -> e=="1").or(e -> e=="2") ).count();
```

Comment: Why would one bother creating a new method just for that? By the way there is no special meaning for naming this function $. Anyway this works too.

Comment: By the way there is no special meaning for naming this function $. Yes there is.. if you want your code to be unreadable...

Comment: I've named this method "either" so its usage reads like this : `either(e -> e=="1").or(e -> e=="2")`

Comment: @bowmore, too bad..your `either` method does also have a `and` method

Comment: @KitKarson That is true, but that hasn't bothered me so far, as I tend to chain ands with additional filter calls on the stream itself. If it really bothers you, you could return a wrapper class around `Predicate` to hide the `and()`.

Answer (score 5):

This is just a small addition to @Chris Jester-Young answer. It is possible to make the expression shorter by using method reference:

```
((Predicate<String>) "1"::equals).or("2"::equals)
```

Answer (score 4):

```java
Arrays.asList("1","2","3").stream().filter( Arrays.asList("1", "2")::contains).count();
```

and yes method "either" is good idea

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long count = Arrays.asList("1","2","3").stream().filter(either("1"::equals).or("2"::equals)).count();
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    private static <T> Predicate<T> either(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        return predicate;
    }
```

or you can use `import static java.util.function.Predicate.isEqual;`
and write `isEqual("1").or(isEqual("2"))`

Answer (score 1):

```
Predicate<String> pred1 =  "1"::equals;
Predicate<String> pred2 =  "2"::equals;

public void tester(){
      Arrays.asList("1","2","3").stream().filter(pred1.or(pred2)).count();
}
```

You can move your separate your conditions to make it possible to recombine them other ways.