# Java 8 lambda error: filter stream by reduced filter collection THEN map THEN collect

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

what to do to compile second method? 
I use solution for predicate reduction

```
predicates.stream().reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(x -> true)
```

I get this solution from following topic: [How to apply multiple predicates to a java.util.Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553761/how-to-apply-multiple-predicates-to-a-java-util-stream)

You know the answer, I'm sure :)

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamTest {
    /**
     * This one works
     */
    @Test
    public void should_filter_map_collect__filterByPredicate() {
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("AA", "AB", "BA", "BB");
        Predicate<String> firstCharIsA = s -> s.charAt(0) == 'A';

        List<String> l = strings.stream()
                .filter(firstCharIsA)
                .map(s -> "_" + s + "_")
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    /**
     * Compilation Error:(43, 25) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>
     */
    @Test
    public void should_filter_map_collect__filterByReducedPredicates() {
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("AA", "AB", "BA", "BB");
        Predicate<String> firstCharIsA = s -> s.charAt(0) == 'A';

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        predicates.add(firstCharIsA);

        List<String> l = strings.stream()
                .filter(predicates.stream().reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(x -> true))
                .map(s -> "_" + s + "_")
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get your error. I did get a warning for an unchecked assignment because you use a raw `Predicate` instead of `Predicate<? super String>` as the type param to your `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
List<Predicate<String>> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
```

solved the error for me.