# Vararg predicates with java 8 stream

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

Given the following function:

```
public static <X> List<X> filterWithVarargPredicates(
        List<X> allProducts,
        Predicate<X>... predicates
    ) {
        for (Predicate<X> predicate : predicates) {
            allProducts = allProducts.stream()
                .filter(predicate)
                .collect(toList());
        }

        return allProducts;
    }
```

Is there any way to consume all the predicates without having to loop through them and re-assign to the list? For instance, it'd be great if `.stream()` had a filter that took varargs, or some way to do that within a single stream.

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest create one new predicate which combine all other:

```
Predicate<X> allPredicates = x -> Arrays.stream(predicates)
          .mapToInt(predicate -> !predicate.test(x)? 1: 0).sum()==0;
allProducts = allProducts.stream().filter(allPredicates).collect(toList());
```

**EDIT**
Better way from @Holger answer [How to apply multiple predicates to a java.util.Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553761/how-to-apply-multiple-predicates-to-a-java-util-stream)

```
Predicate<X> allPredicates = Arrays.stream(predicates)
                                   .reduce(Predicate::and)
                                   .orElse(x->true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a method for combining many predicates into one.

```
@SafeVarargs
static <T> Predicate<T> allTrue(Predicate<? super T>... predicates) {
    return t -> {
        for (Predicate<? super T> predicate : predicates)
            if (!predicate.test(t))
                return false;
        return true;
    };
}
```

Then you can do:

```
allProducts.stream()
           .filter(allTrue(predicates))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That’s a good solution, if you have a larger number of predicates.

Answer (score 0):

It does. Streams are normal objects - you can store them in variables and such.

```
    Stream<X> stream = allProducts.stream();
    for (Predicate<X> predicate : predicates) {
        stream = stream.filter(predicate);
    }

    return stream.collect(toList());
```

Comment: Using hypotetical `foldLeft` stream operation that would be the shortest solution: `Stream.of(predicates).foldLeft(allProducts.stream(), Stream::filter).collect(toList())`. Unfortunately there's no `foldLeft` yet...

Comment: @TagirValeev Nested streams are a surefire way to confuse people, I'm sure.