# How to use stream to apply multiple filters and convert to a List

Tags: java-8, java-stream

here is my problem, 
I have a  List<A> lista1, what I should do is :

1. map<key, List<A>> m = groupby(lista1);

   ```java
   m = lista.stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy);
   ```
2. for every group, return one element with some condition, and make a new list List<A> lista2 = MakeListfromGroup(m)

   ```java
   List<A> lista2;
   for (Map.Entry<key, List<A>> entry : m.entrySet()) {
       A theOne;
       for (A a : entry.getValue()) {
           if(condition){
               theOne = a;
           }
       }
       lista2.add(theOne);
   }
   return lista2;
   ```
3. List<B> listb1 = makeListB(lista2); //here, I cant use stream.map.collect

   ```java
   List<Integer> b1Key;
   List<Integer> b2Key;
   for(A a : lista2){
       b1key.add(a.b1key);
       b2key.add(a.b2key);
   }
   mapb1 = gerfromBD(b1key);
   mapb2 = gerfromBD(b2key);
   List<B> listb1;
   for(A a : lista2){
       listb1.add(new B(mapb1.get(a.b1key),mapb2.get(a.b2key));
   }
    return listb1
   ```
4. B has member B1 b1 and B2 b2, create a new List<B> listb2= applyFilter(list<predicate<B1>>,list<predicate<B2>>)

   ```java
   List<B> listb2;
   nextb:
   for(B b : listb1){
       for(Predicate p: filtreB1){
           if(!p.accept(b.b1)){
               continue nextb;
           }
       }
       for(Predicate p: filtreB2){
           if(!p.accept(b.b2)){
               continue nextb;
           }
       }
       listb2.add(b);
   }
   return listb2;
   ```

Is it possible to put all in one stream? or do the step 4 in a stream way?

thanks in advance

Comment: For step 3 why cant you use stream.map.collect?

Comment: what code have you written? it would help to see more

Comment: I need get some data from the DB to build B. so I cant do it one by one.

Comment: actually I'am using the classic foreach to do this.

Comment: can we see that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the next question, please provide real code instead of incomplete, typo ridden pseudo code.

---

As you need the complete list of `A`s for step 3, you have to collect any potential stream from step 2 into a list anyway. Step 2 and 4 can be simplified by using streams, though:

```
public static List<A> makeListfromGroup(Map<Object, List<A>> m, Predicate<A> condition)
{
    return m.values()
            .stream()
            .map(as -> as.stream().filter(condition).findAny().orElse(null))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

For step 4, you can read how to apply multiple conditions at once [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553761/how-to-apply-multiple-predicates-to-a-java-util-stream):

```
public static List<B> applyFilter(List<B> list, List<Predicate<B1>> filtreB1, List<Predicate<B2>> filtreB2)
{
    return list.stream()
               .filter(b -> filtreB1.stream().allMatch(p -> p.test(b.getB1())))
               .filter(b -> filtreB2.stream().allMatch(p -> p.test(b.getB2())))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```