# Reducing Predicates in Java

Tags: java, reduce, predicate

I have been trying to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553761/how-to-apply-multiple-predicates-to-a-java-util-stream) approach to reduce my predicates into one filter.

Class definition:

```
@Command(name = "Devices", description = "Fetch Devices from SecureTrack", subcommands = {InterfaceCommand.class})
class TufinDevices implements Runnable {
.
.
.
private void filter(TufinDeviceCollection<TufinDevice> devices) {
List<Predicate<? super TufinDevice>> filters = new ArrayList();

if (modelContains != null) {

        System.out.println("modelContains " + Arrays.asList(deviceID));
        Predicate< ? super TufinDevice> deviceFilter = device -> Arrays.stream(modelContains)
                .allMatch(input -> device.getModel().toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase()));

        filters.add(deviceFilter);

    }

if (hostNameContains != null) {
        Predicate<TufinDevice> deviceFilter = device -> Arrays.stream(hostNameContains)
                .allMatch(input -> device.getHostName().toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase()));

        filters.add(deviceFilter);
    }
 devices.stream().filter(filters.stream().reduce(Predicate::or).orElse(t->true));
 }
```

I do not understand how this line of code is supposed to work.

```
devices.stream().filter(filters.stream().reduce(Predicate::or).orElse(t->true));
```

How does that line need to be implemented in order to work. Its complaining that

```
Predicate<CAP1> can't be converted to Predicate<? super CAP2>
```

Comment: what's `filters`?

Comment: just updated the post with that info.

Comment: Yes, Tufin device is a custom class.

Comment: The code is contained in a method, within a class. I will update with both.

Comment: Its complicated because it is a Picocli project. I'll post the line though.

Comment: OK, I see the problem now.  The compiler can't tell whether your `deviceFilter` inside the first `if` block matches the type of `filters`.  I would recommend declaring `deviceFilter` as `Predicate<TufinDevice>`, instead of `Predicate<? super TufinDevice>`.

Comment: Ok, that did it, but in the future how can i pass something that possible extends TufinDevice?

Comment: Try `<? extends TufinDevice>`?