# Composing Bi-Predicate in non-static context

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I have interface defined for all Filters:

```
public interface Filter<I, C> extends BiPredicate<I, C> {}
```

I inject in all these filter as a list in my Service class:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private List<BiPredicate<Status, Request>> filters;

    public List<Status> getStatus(final Request requestParameter) {
      final List<Status> summaries == this.repo
              .summary(requestParameter)
              .stream()
              .reduce(BiPredicate::and).orElse((x, y) -> true)
              .test();  //arg1=status from stream, arg2=requestParameter
  }
}
```

I am struggling to complete the above and apply all the filters from the collections `filters`. 
How do I pass `status` and `requestParameter` to `test()`? I am also getting an error `non-static method cannot be referenced from static context`?

Is there a better way than the following which is what I attempted:

1. Initialise `allFilters` as field:

   ```
   private BiPredicate<Status, Request> allFilters = 
       filters.stream().reduce(BiPredicate::and).orElse((x, y) -> true);
   ```
2. Then invoke call:

   ```
   this.repo.statusSummary(request)
       .stream()
       .filter(status -> applyFilters(status, request))
       .collect(toList());`
   ```

applyFilters():

```
private boolean applyFilters(Status status, Request request) {
    return this.allFilters.test(status, request);
}
```

Comment: By "better", do you mean a way to do it in one statement?

Comment: by better I mean to say to avoid initialising `allFilters` as class variable and instead combine the functions in the method and test and return the result.

Comment: In my opinion, what you've implemented is better than what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `allMatch` as

```
final List<Status> summaries ==this.repo
        .summary(requestParameter)
        .stream()
        .filter(r -> filters.stream()
                .allMatch(f -> f.test(s, requestParameter)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList();
```

Comment: is call to `allMatch()` do exactly same as my answer ? It will apply and check against all defined filters ?

Comment: @M06H yes it would `test` for all existing filters in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [answer from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553761/how-to-apply-multiple-predicates-to-a-java-util-stream)

```
final List<Status> getStatus = this.repo
                .summary(request)
                .stream()
                .filter(status-> this.filters.stream().reduce(BiPredicate::and).orElse((x, y) -> true).test(status, request))
                .collect(toList());
```