# Composition of method reference

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, function-composition, method-reference

This is related to this question: [How to do function composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834611/java-8-function-composition)

I noticed that a method reference can be assigned to a variable declared as `Function`, and so I assume it should have `andThen` or `compose` function, and hence I expect that we can compose them directly. But apparently we need to assign them to a variable declared as `Function` first (or type-cast before invocation) before we can call `andThen` or `compose` on them.

I suspect I might have some misconception about how this should work.

So my questions:

1. Why do we need to type-cast or assign it to a variable first before we can call the `andThen` method?
2. What exactly is the type of method reference that it needs to be done in this way?

Sample code below.

```
public class MyMethods{
    public static Integer triple(Integer a){return 3*a;}
    public static Integer quadruple(Integer a){return 4*a;}

    public int operate(int num, Function<Integer, Integer> f){
        return f.apply(num);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyMethods methods = new MyMethods();
        int three = methods.operate(1, MyMethods::triple); // This is fine
        // Error below
        // int twelve = methods.operate(1, (MyMethods::triple).andThen(MyMethods::quadruple));
        // But this one is fine
        Function<Integer, Integer> triple = MyMethods::triple;
        Function<Integer, Integer> quadruple = MyMethods::quadruple;
        int twelve = methods.operate(1, triple.andThen(quadruple));
        // This one is also fine
        int twelve2 = methods.operate(1, ((Function<Integer, Integer>)MyMethods::triple).andThen(MyMethods::quadruple));
    }
}
```

---

#### More description on the error

In Eclipse it's highlighted with the error message:

> The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

[image: Eclipse error about functional interface]

and in Java 8 compiler the error is:

```
java8test.java:14: error: method reference not expected here
        int twelve = methods.operate(1, (MyMethods::triple).andThen(MyMethods::quadruple));
                                         ^
1 error
```

(actually, why is the error in Eclipse different from the one from Java 8 compiler?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Brian Goetz (project lead for Java lambdas) says, ["Lambda expressions have no intrinsic type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396544/java-8-lambda-predicate-chaining/24396579#comment37736308_24396579) (which applies to method references too). This is why you need to cast (or assign) to type `Function` before its methods become available.

The reason Eclipse shows different error messages from the JDK compiler (javac) is that Eclipse uses its own Java compiler, called ecj, which is a totally different program from javac. This is, BTW, why Eclipse can run on the JRE, without needing a full JDK install.

Comment: I see, that question is about Predicate, that's why I couldn't find it in my search. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 16):

You can get away without type casts or temporary variables if you create a `static` helper method (where all functions are parameters rather than method invocation receivers):

```
static <T,V,R> Function<V, R> chain(
    Function<? super V, ? extends T> f1, Function<? super T, R> f2) {

    return f2.compose(f1);
}
```

Then you can simply say:

```
int twelve = methods.operate(1, chain(MyMethods::triple, MyMethods::quadruple));
```

however, keep in mind that chaining method references this way is neither shorter in source code nor more efficient at runtime compared to a simple lambda expression:

```
int twelve = methods.operate(1, i -> quadruple(triple(i)));
```

Note how the last solution does not require type casts, additional variables nor helper methods. Method references are a good tool if you have an already existing method that fits where a function is required but composing a function out of multiple method references is not really useful (in most cases).

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I forgot that we can revert back to using lambda expression. Thank you for the input!